# Pipe transform use reduce for array of object

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, pipe, reduce

this is my Interface file :

```
export interface ListCount {
  centre?: string;
  cause?: string;
  totalTime?: number;
}
```

I am trying to make reduce to array of objects with pipe transform :

```
export class SumPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(items: ListCount[], attr: string): number {
    return items.reduce((a, b) => a + b[attr], 0);
  }
}
```

and in compent HTML I looking to make sum of totalTime

```
{{ (delayCount$ | async) | sum:'totalTime'}}
```

But I have this error :

```
error TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'ListCount'.
```

Then I change the param `attr: string` to `attr: keyof ListCount`
and still have this error :

```
error TS2365: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'number' and 'string | number'.
```

and

```
error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

Any help please

Comment: Why not `attr` is number like `transform(items: ListCount[], attr: number): number {`

Comment: @er-sho: Because it's the property name whose values is to be summed up.

Comment: What is the purpose of passing a `totalTime` when it's the only type (`number`) that could be summed up in the array? Could there be any other properties of type `number` later?

Comment: @er-sho: The value contained in the property `totalTime` is of type `number`. But in context of trying to access the property using `obj['totalTime']`, `totalTime` is a string.

Comment: try `reduce((a:number, b:any)=>....)`

Comment: @MichaelD, got it what OP needs to say.

Comment: Why don't you just do this?  `return items.reduce((a, b, index) => a + b[index].totalTime, 0);`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

- restrict attr to point to numeric properties
- take into account that properties can be optional. Use zero for those.
- alternatively filter out missing (undefined) values.

```
export interface ListCount {
  centre?: string;
  cause?: string;
  totalTime?: number;
  otherTime?: number;
}

type NumericKeys<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends number ? P : never;
}[keyof T];


type NumericListCountKey = NumericKeys<Required<ListCount>>;

class SumPipe  {
  transform(items: ListCount[], attr: NumericListCountKey): number {
    const elemes = items.map(elem => elem[attr]);
    return elemes.reduce((prev: number, currentVal) => prev + (currentVal ? currentVal : 0), 0);
  }
}


// alternatively, with filter
class SumPipe2  {
  static isNumber(n: number | undefined): n is number {
    return n != null;
  } 

  transform(items: ListCount[], attr: NumericListCountKey): number {
    const elems = items.map(elem => elem[attr])
                       .filter(SumPipe2.isNumber);
    return elems.reduce((prev: number, currentVal) => prev + currentVal, 0);
  }
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgGQQGcYBhCAVxTgG8AoOOXFKYAfgC44SpkBzANwMmmCkXZce-IYxgQYmADYAVBAFsJcJBTUAjNDLjyAFmlUbOWnfqhCAvnTowAnmDwA5HWgTYA0sGciAB5lAD44AF5aYUYAbQAFRCQ4AGsAiHQ4ZQBdLmUE7LhQVCQAEyIrPTQ4NjhEriRgADcDOjtYtOcMrOyhRxc3OE8NXmxCEnIqGH9nSKGvUZnggCVgAEcKBFZSoPGyShRQ0L7sRUwiCoBlHXiEQejZKEwkInRoNQAKBFQ1Ii49yYoWLZAA0cEwMBgUC4w28Y2I%20ymMwAlA1rNV6IxGNgIC94MBFMANBUot8iUQAHRqTBgD4EomRcL0tSxCFQ7LIwyMVgwChQZLM4CU7YUXAfD5gVhNNFVKBg7B81goABqSmRjLgkuacAA1HAPgqoEqYKrFDUmIrgCqlHAuAAGZFgh2GBx2IA)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your code compiles without issues and works. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jij964) is a working stackblitz. If it fails on your local environment, perhaps try checking TS version, try restarting the Angular CLI, look for other issues or at least provided information on which line exactly the error is thrown.

There are a few issues with your code though.

- As others have noted, passing any `attr` to the pipe and using the bracket notation to get the property value makes no sense. Only object accepted by the pipe is `ListCount[]`, so it HAVE to be `totalTime` that gets summed as it's the only numeric property. It would make sense if you made more generic pipe that would accept `any[]` though.
- Your pipe is not guarded for your use-case. `totalTime` is an optional property, meaning that if any item doesn't have `totalTime` defined (which it can, according to your interface) the pipe will return `NaN`. Not sure if that's the desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) article, `reduce()` has an optional index, which points to the current index in the array. Knowing this, I'd opt for the following solution, leaving out `attr` entirely.

```
return items.reduce((a, b, index) => a + b[index].totalTime, 0);
```